# Buttons allowing me to show specific data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

i need help trying to show up specific data and this time i need to sort out a table by clicking on genders. here is my html

```
<center>
    <h1>Russestyret 2018</h1>
<br>
 <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="Index.html">Hjem</a>
            <a href="Registreringer.html">Registrering</a>
            <a href="Index.html">Arragementer</a>
        </nav>
 </header>
 <hr>



<img src="bilder/russestyret2.png" width="400px">


<h4>Arrangementer</h4>
<form id="regarrangement">
    <label>Arrangør: <input id="inparrangør" type="text" required></label>
    <label>Adresse: <input id="inpregadress"type="text"required></label>
    <label>Postadresse:<input id="inppostadresse" type="text"required></label>
    <label>Poststed: <input id="inppoststed" type="tex"required></label>
    <label>Pris: <input id=inppris type="text"required></label>
    <button type="submit">Send inn</button>
</form>



<h4>Registrer en russ ved å fylle ut skjema under. Alle felter må fylles ut.</h4>
<form id="registrering">
    <label>Navn: <input id="inpnavn" placeholder="Raahim Khan" type="text" required></label>
    <label>Adresse: <input id="inpadresse" type="text" placeholder="Adresse 12" required></label>
    <label>Mobilnummer: <input id="inpmobilnummer" placeholder="12345678" required></label>
    <label>Kjønn: 
      <select id="inpkjønn" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Velg kjønn</option>
        <option>Mann</option>
        <option>Kvinne</option>
        <option>intetkjønn</option>
      </select>
      <label>Arrangement: <select id="inparrang"></select></label>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Send inn</button>
</form>
 <br>
 <br>
```

buttons allowing me to see either all the registered russ or only menn, women or neuter, visAlleruss stands for show allruss, visIntetKjønn for show neuter and so on with men and women.:

```
<button class="vis" onclick="visAlleruss()">Vis alle</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visMenn()">Vis Menn</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visKvinner()">Vis Kvinner</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visIntetkjønn()">Vis intetkjønn</button>



<table border="2px" width="500px;">
    <tr><th>Navn</th><th>Adresse</th><th>Mobilnummer</th><th>Kjønn</th><th>Arrangør</th><th>Adresse</th><th>Postadresse</th><th>Poststed</th><th>Pris</th><th>Slett:</th></tr>
    <tbody id="txttabell"></tbody>
</table>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
```

function below is to register russ/arrangement and bring them into the innerHTML

```
//Register "arrangement":
function registrerearrangement(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // Henter ut verdiene til input-feltene
    var arrangør = inpArrangør.value;
    var adresse = inpAdresse.value;
    var postadresse = inpPostadresse.value;
    var poststed = inpPoststed.value;
    var pris = inpPris.value;
    var russ = inpRuss.value;


    inpArrangør.value = "";
    inpAdresse.value = "";
    inpPostadresse.value = "";
    inpPoststed.value = "";
    inpPris.value = "";
    inpRuss.value = "";


    arrangement.push({
        "arrangør" : arrangør,
        "adresse" : adresse,
        "postadresse" : postadresse,
        "poststed" : poststed,
        "pris" : pris,
        "russ" : russ
    });    
}

//bring data from firebase into txtTabell.innerHTML
function hentArrangement(snapshot){
    var pk = snapshot.key;
    var nyTime = snapshot.val();
    var russRef = database.ref("russ/" + nyTime.russ);
    russRef.on("value", function(snapshotruss) {
        var pkk = snapshotruss.key;
        var russObj = snapshotruss.val();
        txtTabell.innerHTML += `
        <tr id="${pk}">
        <td><label class="russlabel" onclick="edit('${pk}')">${nyTime.arrangør}</label><input type="text" class="editItem" style="display:none"></td>
        <td>${nyTime.adresse}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.postadresse}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.poststed}</td>
        <td>${nyTime.pris}</td>
        <td>${russObj.navn}</td>
        <td>${russObj.russadresse}</td>
        <td>${russObj.mobilnr}</td>
        <td>${russObj.kjonn}</td>
        <td><label class="delete" onclick="slett('${pk}','${pkk}')"><button>Slett</button></label></td>
        </tr>`;
    });
} 


//bring russ:
function hentRuss(snapshot){
    var russNoekkel = snapshot.key;
    var russInfo = snapshot.val();

    inpRuss.innerHTML += `<option value="${russNoekkel}">${russInfo.navn}</option>`;
};


//register "russ":
function registrerruss(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var navn = inpNavn.value;
    var russadresse = inpRussadresse.value;
    var mobilnr = inpMobil.value;
    var kjonn = inpKjønn.value;


    inpNavn.value = "";
    inpRussadresse.value = "";
    inpMobil.value = "";
    inpKjønn.value = "";


    russ.push({
        "navn" : navn,
        "russadresse" : russadresse,
        "mobilnr" : mobilnr,
        "kjonn" : kjonn
    });

}

skjema.onsubmit = registrerearrangement;
skjema2.onsubmit = registrerruss;
```

function below are functions for the button, the reason i am doing .on("child_added", hentRuss) is because the russ objects are the objects including the gender btw kjonn stands for gender.

```
    function visAlleruss(){
      txtTabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .on("child_added", hentRuss);    
}

    function visMenn(){
      txtTabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjonn")
      .equalTo("Mann")
      .on("child_added", hentRuss);    
}


    function visKvinner(){
      txtTabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjonn")
      .equalTo("Kvinne")
      .on("child_added", hentRuss);    
}

    function visIntetkjønn(){
      txtTabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjonn")
      .equalTo("intetkjønn")
      .on("child_added", hentRuss);    
}
```

Comment: I think it's tired to read and understand all of your code. Can you tell me the exact problem you got, like some errors of js?

Comment: i understand but whenever i click the button to show me russ out of their genders i get an error: "Typeerror: Cannot read property 'navn' of null" but when i type in the "navn" data which is the name, it works fine untill i try to only show them from their genders

Comment: It will be easier to find your problem if put your code to 
 jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) (better is to just put the problem part)